# FXOS8700CQ accelerometer sensor interrupt output not working

Tags: microcontroller, pic, accelerometer, nxp, gyroscope

I am trying to get interrupt output on INT2 pin of FXOS8700CQ sensor when the FXOS8700CQ sensor is moved, but anyhow i cannot do this. i did setup the register perfectly. please check my following register setup code:

```
void FXOS8700CQ_Init(void)
{
FXOS8700CQ_writeReg(FXOS8700_REGISTER_CTRL_REG2, 0x40); // Reset all registers to POR values
__delay_ms(1);
FXOS8700CQ_writeReg(FXOS8700_REGISTER_XYZ_DATA_CFG, 0x00); // +/-2g range with 0.244mg/LSB
FXOS8700CQ_writeReg(FXOS8700_REGISTER_MCTRL_REG1, 0x1F); // Hybrid mode (accelerometer + magnetometer), max OSR
FXOS8700CQ_writeReg(FXOS8700_REGISTER_CTRL_REG2, 0x00); // High Resolution mode
FXOS8700CQ_writeReg(FXOS8700_REGISTER_CTRL_REG3, 0x02); // Push-pull, active High interrupt
FXOS8700CQ_writeReg(FXOS8700_REGISTER_CTRL_REG4, 0x1D); // DRDY, Freefall/Motion, P/L and tap ints enabled
FXOS8700CQ_writeReg( FXOS8700_REGISTER_CTRL_REG5, 0x00); // all interrupt on INT2
FXOS8700CQ_writeReg( FXOS8700_REGISTER_CTRL_REG1, 0x35); // ODR = 3.125Hz, Reduced noise, Active mode

}
```

I only configure the above register to get interrupt output on INT2 pin that fed to main MCU, i did not configure the other register, i dont need anything else, i need only interrupt on INT2. do i need to configure other register to get interrupt output.  can anyone please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "move" you mean changing the orientation (from portrait to landscape and vice versa), your config is correct and I suggest debugging the code (or using printf) to re-check config registers and also watching status register values before and after changing the orientation.
But if you mean linear movement of the sensor, then you should enable acceleration interrupt in your config, which you haven't set it. Based on the datasheet, to enable acceleration interrupt in the `CTRL_REG4` you got to set the second bit of the `CTRL_REG4`. But in your code it's not enabled.

```
FXOS8700CQ_writeReg(FXOS8700_REGISTER_CTRL_REG4, 0x1F); // all previous interrupts plus acceleration
```